# How can I add the featured image functionality to a custom taxonomy?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, post-thumbnails

I would like to be able to use the 'featured image' functionality, found on post types, for a custom taxonomy.

I have a taxonomy called 'collections' and I would like each collection to have a featured image. I will then use the featured image in a custom template that will show all of the collection, their titles and featured images.

I need the uploaded image to be resized into the custom image sizes that I have set in my theme.

There is a similar question here: [Can I set a default featured image for a category?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5013/can-i-set-a-default-featured-image-for-a-category) However, the top answer won't work for me, and I can't rely on a plugin.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks,

Keith

Comment: if you want to use a plugin here is the best one for it. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/ If you don't want to use any plugin you can checkout the plugin code to add codes to your theme.

Answer (score 6):

It's a little complex, but you can add custom meta to taxonomies. http://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/

You could pretty easily integrate a WP media uploader field that would allow you to enter an image into the field.

Comment: why pass 2 parameters 'add_action( 'edited_category', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );' when the function only has 1 argument?  Thanks.

Comment: The function accepts two parameters, but two don't have to be passed.

Comment: Why not leave it is add_action('edited_category', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta'); instead?  I have seen this in a few examples where the function only accepts one parameter but the add_action declares 2.  Just wondering why this would be.  Thanks.

Comment: If the function can have 2 parameters, then the 2 should be set in the add_action, but it does not have to be set in the call back function.

Answer (score 1):

With [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) you can achieve this very easily:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

[image: adding image to taxonomy in wordpress]

[image: addimg image to term in wordpress]